# How to reference variables in multiple IOS View Controllers

Tags: ios, model-view-controller, design-patterns, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I'm asking what is probably a fundamental question but I'm relatively new to iOS and Object Oriented Programming:

Question:
If I have a simple app with 2 Views & View Controllers that receives input from each, how should I structure my program so that I can reference the values that were inputed in each view controller and take these values, add them together (as an example), and then output it to say a 3rd View Controller?

If this was all done in the same controller then I can do it but the issue is where can I store this so that the data is available across multiple controllers?

Fundamentally I'm not sure where the 'processing (addition) should occur. Should this be in another class, or AppDelegate? Is this termed the 'model' in MVC and can multiple View Controllers reference the same model?

I'm sure this is really basic stuff but an example or reference to material will really help clarify this for me.

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use NSUserDefaults to store the shared data or you can implement your own shared storage object as [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), [here's](http://db-in.com/blog/2011/12/objective-c-singleton/) one tutorial for creating singleton object in obj-c with demo project.

Answer (score 0):

My personal pattern is a variant of the Model-View-Controller pattern.  For each screen I have a ViewController, a UIView, a model class to hold data displayed by the view and a helper class to hold all of my business logic for that view.  Those classes reference one another so that if you know one you can get to the others.  I also link my model classes and helper classes in hierarchies that correspond to the controller hierarchy and that's how I solve the problem you describe.  For a given view you can get to its helper and model class instance and from there you can navigate to any helper and model instance for the entire app.

There are probably better ways to do this, but that's how I do it.